# YouTube API setting playlist position

Tags: youtube, position, playlist

I'm using Version 2 of the YouTube API in PHP and have been so for over a year. Everything worked fine till around 2 weeks ago. I then noticed problems with the playlists, particularly adding video entries to playlists and setting the position.

My request headers and payload are correct, according to the API Documentation. I also receive a `200` Response Code and in the response body my playlist entry has a `yt:position` of 1. But checking the playlist the position is actually at the end, not the beginning.

I would like to know if anyone is having similar problems and if they perhaps have found a solution?

Below is a sample of my request / response:

> > Response:
> >
> > HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> >  X-GData-User-Country: DE
> >  Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=entry
> >  GData-Version:
> >     2.1
> >  ETag:
> >  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> >  Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 17:17:20 GMT
> >  Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 17:17:20 GMT
> >     Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
> >  X-Content-Type-Options:
> >     nosniff
> >  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> >  X-XSS-Protection: 1;
> >     mode=block
> >  Server: GSE Connection: close
> >
> > <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'
> >     xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
> >     xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
> >     xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' gd:etag=''>
> >     ...
> >         <yt:position>
> >             1
> >         </yt:position>
> >  </entry>
> >
> > Request:
> >
> > PUT /feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST/PLAYLIST_ENTRY HTTP/1.1
> >  Accept: */*
> >  Host: gdata.youtube.com
> >  Connection: close
> >     X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
> >  User-Agent:
> >     Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.8
> >  authorization: GoogleLogin
> >     auth=AUTH_KEY
> >  GData-Version: 2
> >  Accept-encoding:
> >     identity
> >  Content-Type: application/atom+xml
> >  Content-Length:
> >     166
> >
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
> >     xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"><yt:position>1</yt:position></entry>